# biztalk: using first node xml file to decide what map to use

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have a problem in my project i have to create orchestration and base o first node of xml file i have to decide what map will be use. Any idea how to do it? 
 I try to use decide shape and in decide shape use xslt query to find first node equal particular node decide shape will send it to particular map. 
is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that would use a receive location for each type of message would be to use a Listen shape in the orchestration. Each branch of the listen would be expecting a different message type (or root node as you put it) and you could apply the appropriate map. Then, assuming you are mapping to a canonical schema, the rest of the orchestration would be the same regardless of input message type.

[image: listen shape.]

In the image the orchestration is using a listen shape to listen for 3 types of message. It's mostly for replay-ability for when the orchestration fails at different stages, I can inject it back into the flow after a fix is made.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some suggestions:

1. If the schema can be resolved by the XmlDisassembler, the engine will apply the matching Map on the Receive Port automatically.
2. If the number of different Maps is manageable, say 4 or 5, and very unlikely to change, then sure, the decide shape is a workable approach.
3. Be sure to carefully examine the differences in the Maps.  I've had times when the planners believed the maps were significantly more different then in reality.  If the difference is a handful of differing codes or conditional fields, maybe one Map can handle all cases.

Comment: i have only 2 maps, 2 different type of xml file(first node different)  I am nor sure:
1.  create one receive shape ?

Comment: As boatseller has said, if the namespace or root node of the two XML files are different and you are using the XMLDisassembler in the receive location pipeline than you can have both maps on the same receive port and BizTalk will automatically select the correct map to use.  The other option is to have to different receive locations & ports even if they come from the same location if you can apply a different file mask for each type.

Comment: Can you clarify.  By 'first node' do you mean the Root Element?  If so, then to BizTalk they are different message types.