# biztalk xpath query in orchestration

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I am using decide shape in orchestration and I  receive 2 xml file. 
   and i have  filter that file using xpatch because depend first node i have to process in different map. I use xpach  statement to get find if the first node equal specific value if yes it will process if not it wil be send to second map. 
how i should do that? I  do not do it usually and try to find out how my statement should look

```
  xpath(ACKSchema(name(/*))== CstmrPmtStsRpt;
```

1. How to check if xml file equal specific condition?
   thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [biztalk: using first node xml file to decide what map to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616655/biztalk-using-first-node-xml-file-to-decide-what-map-to-use)

Comment: Same question as the previous thread.  By 'first node' do you mean the Document Element?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [xpath query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee268159(v=bts.10).aspx) function to probe the value in the message, or set the value. The syntax for receiving a string value is

```
variable = xpath(BiztalkMessage,"string(xpath-query)");
```

To set a value in the message

```
xpath(BiztalkMessage,"xpath-query") = value
```

An easy way to locate the xpath you want to use is to open the schema in the Visual Studio BizTalk project, and select the node that will hold your value. Then look at the properties window and use the 'Instance Xpath' value (see [this post](http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2007/11/30/XPath+The+Hidden+Language+Of+BizTalk.aspx) for more details)

[image]

The xpath query can be a bit verbose, and depending on your situation you could shorten it (with a small loss of fidelity). If you are comparing a string value, you'll want to use the string function;

```
xpath(msgTestMessage,"string(//MyNode)") == "TestValue"
```

Without the [xpath string function](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string), you'll be receiving the equivalent of a nodeset, rather than the value.

Comment: Is this give me name of first node 
depend of first node I have to process xml file using different maps
i have two different first node name no what value have that node but node name.

Comment: Ah, so its not the value of the node, it's the name?

Comment: Yes I need use node name for filtering in my decide shape
also I have to process  check that node in two different xml file

Comment: Use the BizTalk message type in the expression shape?

Comment: Jay's answer above is the correct way. I'm not sure how you get two different messages into your orch unless they are received seperately or untyped. If you *have* to, you could use 'Message_1(BTS.MessageType) == "http://SoapFaults.RequestMsg#Root"' in an expression, but it really doesn't make much sense!

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to use the xpath and decide shape at all if your two xml files have different root nodes.

[Using direct bound ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa949234.aspx) BizTalk can route your messages to the correct "subscriber" for you automatically. You drop the two input messages into the message box database. If you create one subscriber for each message type BizTalk will send the messages to the correct subscriber for you.

BizTalk uses the target namespace and the root node name to decide which subscriber gets which message.